# Pipe Input Error when Processing MOV Files

Tags: go, ffmpeg, pipe, stdin

I'm working on a project in Go where I'm trying to process video files using ffmpeg through pipes. However, I'm encountering issues when I try to use a pipe for the input stream.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
func main() {
    inputPath := "video.MOV"
    fileOutput := "output.mp4"

    fileBytes, err := os.Open(inputPath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    outFile, err := os.Create(fileOutput)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer outFile.Close()

    cmd := exec.Command(
        "ffmpeg",
        "-y",
        "-i", "pipe:0", // It is not works.
        "-vf", fmt.Sprintf("scale=-1:%s", "480"),
        "-c:v", "libx264",
        "-crf", "23", // You can adjust this value for desired quality
        "-c:a", "aac", // Assumes the audio codec to be aac, change as needed
        "-strict", "experimental",
        "-f", "mp4",
        "-movflags", "empty_moov",
        "pipe:1",
    )
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    cmd.Stdin = fileBytes
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    if _, err := io.Copy(outFile, stdout); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

When running the above code, I get the following error:

> [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000025c65c5eb00] stream 1, offset 0x24: partial file
> [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000025c65c5eb00] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none(smpte170m/smpte432/bt709), 1920x1440, 19882 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
> Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
> Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
>
> ...
> [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000025c65c5eb00] stream 1, offset 0x24: partial file
> Error demuxing input file 0: Invalid data found when processing input
> pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input
> Cannot determine format of input stream 0:0 after EOF
> Error marking filters as finished

Interestingly, this error only occurs when I use the input pipe. When using a direct file path (-i inputPath), everything works fine.

Has anyone encountered similar issues when piping inputs to ffmpeg in Go?

Comment: Maybe specifying input and output pipes is not so straightforward (or impossible) seeing ffmpeg doc examples: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#pipe. Also not sure about the last paragraph of that doc section, about the mov files, it's relevant to your use case or not... Does it work it you use a file path for output but a pipe for input?

Comment: @mortalis No, it doesn't work. I just don't want to save the file somewhere, is there any way?